# resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed Xcode 8 error?

Tags: ios, xcode8, macos-sierra

I am receiving error while running old project in Xcode 8. Same project running completely flow less in Xcode 7.

I also apply solution mentioned in following links

1. [Code Sign Error in macOS Sierra Xcode 8 : resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-sierra-xcode-8-resource-fork-finder-information-or)
2. [Code Signing Error Whenever I try replacing stock files in new SceneKit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830758/code-signing-error-whenever-i-try-replacing-stock-files-in-new-scenekit-applicat)

But not able to resole it.
I also created new certificates, Bundle Identifier and respective provisioning profiles but same result.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem using solution 1. in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-sierra-xcode-8-resource-fork-finder-information-or). You can refer same for solution.

Answer (score 2):

When running into this periodically during development, as a temporary workaround you can disable code signing then remove the extended attributes one time before distribution to save time. Add the user defined build setting at the target:

```
CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED = No
```

Comment: This should be upvoted. Nothing else worked in my case. I was compiling a bundle that used for testing purposes and it doesn't need to be signed.