# Craslytics Beta distribution of a React Native app getting "Unable to download app. [APP_NAME] could not be installed at this time"

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

Context:

1. React Native application targeted at iOS.
2. Using Xcode to build a release build directly into my iPhone works
3. I am using iOS 10
4. I have not released my app into App Store
5. Archiving and releasing into Crashlytics Beta works, my test user got the invite.
6. I've checked my UDID and it is the same as the value inside *.mobileprovision file.
7. I'm not on any paid Apple developer program. Just building apps with my Apple ID.

The problem only comes when my test user attempts to download the app. He will see the alert "Unable to download app. [APP_NAME] could not be installed at this time"

Comment: Same issue with our internal app, looks like it is a global issue.

Comment: try to install it over VPN.

Comment: @MelihMucuk why would that help?

Comment: I dont know why, but I couldn't install some apps, then I tried over vpn and it works.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. would love to know if you found a workaround/

Comment: @user805981 problem solved after buying the Apple developer license

Comment: @ShawnLim Is this a requirement to use crashlytics and other beta testing services? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I wrote it to Fabric support and they told me to do that

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was caused by silently failed code signing (resigning) on our Jenkins CI.
We've updated to macOS Sierra and "resigning" step failed with a new error: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html, then build was distributed via Fabric as usual, and "Unable to download app" appeared on install.

So I fixed my issue by executing this command in a project folder before resigning:

```
xattr -rc .
```

Here is the question and answer that helped me out https://stackoverflow.com/a/39373807/3978736

If that's not your case, then you can find a more comprehensive list of causes here in similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21537619/3978736